# Code for changing multiple .img files into .png, then into numpy array

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, default.png

I'm doing a convolutional neural network classification and currently all my tiles are in .img format (thanks ArcMap). I know I need to get them in .png format, but haven't found code that could convert a whole folder of them. Is that doable?

Eventually I also need to get all those .pngs into a numpy array. I found basic code that will do it for just .png, but is there a way to convert the whole folder at once?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you looked at pillow? Pillow allows conversion among picture formats and conversion to numpy arrays. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is doable, just use Python [Pil](https://python-pillow.org/)! and loop over all files in the folder with glob.

Some example code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import glob

counter = 0
for image in glob.glob("/Users/Testfolder/*.jpg"):
    counter = counter + 1
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.save('/Users/Testfolder/' + (str(counter)+'img.png'))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).